# How to rename folders with specific name in them and keep case

Tags: batch-file

I would like to know if it is possible to rename all folders that have a specific word inside their name but still keep the lower and upper case of the name.

For example rename all folders that have "rescicao" (no matter upper or lower case) to "rescisao" but keep the original case:

- Minha Rescicao -> Minha Rescisao
- RESCICAO -> RESCISAO
- esta rescicao -> esta rescisao

Meanwhile in my batch it only renames the exact way I specify:

- Minha Rescicao -> Minha Rescisao
- RESCICAO -> Rescisao
- esta rescicao  -> esta Rescisao

Is there a way to rename but keep the original case?

This is the batch:

```
@echo off
chcp 1252 > Nul
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:: Folder structure to be renamed:
set Folder=C:\Users\Ricardo\Desktop\Clientes

:: Phrase to be renamed:
set Ori1=RESCICAO

:: To be substituted by this:
set Sub1=Rescisao

For /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /s /ad "%Folder%" ^& echo %Folder% ^|sort /r ^|find /i "%Ori1%"') do call :Rename1 "%%a"
exit

:Rename1
set "NameP1=%~nx1"
set "NameP1=!NameP1:%Ori1%=%Sub1%!"
if not "%NameP1%"=="%~nx1" ren "%~1" "%NameP1%"
goto :EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

For your particular situation you could use the following script, which just replaces the character `c` at (zero-based) position 5 in the (space-separated) word `Rescicao` rather than having to predefine lots of combinations of upper- and lower-case letters:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_ROOT=%~dp0."   & rem // (target directory)
set "_WORD=RESCICAO" & rem // (specific word in upper-case letters)
set /A "_POS=5"      & rem // (position of character to be replaced)
set "_UP=S"          & rem // (new upper-case letter)
set "_LO=s"          & rem // (new lower-case letter)

rem // Calculate position behind character of interest:
set /A "NEXT=_POS+1"
rem // Change to target directory:
pushd "%_ROOT%" && (
    rem // Loop through directories whose names contain specific word:
    for /F "eol=| delims=" %%D in ('dir /B /A:D-H-S "*%_WORD%*"') do (
        rem // Store current directory name, initialise buffer and flag:
        set "NAME=%%D" & set "COLL= " & set "FLAG="
        rem // Toggle delayed expansion to avoid problems with `!`:
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        rem // Loop through space-separated words of directory name:
        for %%I in ("!NAME: =" "!") do (
            rem // Store current word:
            endlocal & set "ITEM=%%~I"
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            rem // Check whether current word matches specific word:
            if /I "!ITEM!"=="!_WORD!" (
                rem // Check case of letter at given character position:
                if "!ITEM:~%_POS%,1!"=="!_WORD:~%_POS%,1!" (
                    rem // Replace letter with new upper-case one:
                    set "ITEM=!ITEM:~,%_POS%!!_UP!!ITEM:~%NEXT%!"
                ) else (
                    rem // Replace letter with new lower-case one:
                    set "ITEM=!ITEM:~,%_POS%!!_LO!!ITEM:~%NEXT%!"
                )
                rem // Set flag to indicate character replacement:
                set "FLAG=#"
            )
            rem /* Assemble new directory name, maintain flag and
            rem    overcome `endlocal` barrier: */
            for /F "delims=" %%C in ("!COLL! !ITEM!") do (
                if defined FLAG (endlocal & set "FLAG=#") else endlocal
                set "COLL=%%~C"
                setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            )
        )
        rem // Rename directory only when needed:
        if defined FLAG ren "!NAME!" "!COLL:~2!"
        endlocal
    )
    rem // Return from target directory:
    popd
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

---

Here is a generalised approach that does not rely on certain specific letters and character positions:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_ROOT=%~dp0."   & rem // (target directory)
set "_WORD=Rescicao" & rem // (specific word to be replaced)
set "_REPL=Rescisao" & rem // (specific word for replacement)

rem // Change to target directory:
pushd "%_ROOT%" && (
    for /F "eol=| delims=" %%D in ('dir /B /A:D-H-S "*%_WORD%*"') do (
    rem // Loop through directories whose names contain specific word:
        rem // Store current directory name, initialise buffer and flag:
        set "NAME=%%D" & set "COLL= " & set "FLAG="
        rem // Toggle delayed expansion to avoid problems with `!`:
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        rem // Loop through space-separated words of directory name:
        for %%I in ("!NAME: =" "!") do (
            rem // Store current word:
            endlocal & set "ITEM=%%~I"
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            rem // Check whether current word matches specific word:
            if /I "!ITEM!"=="!_WORD!" (
                rem // Do the actual replacement with case preservation:
                call :REPLACEMENT ITEM ITEM _REPL
                rem // Set flag to indicate word replacement:
                set "FLAG=#"
            )
            rem /* Assemble new directory name, maintain flag and
            rem    overcome `endlocal` barrier: */
            for /F "delims=" %%C in ("!COLL! !ITEM!") do (
                if defined FLAG (endlocal & set "FLAG=#") else endlocal
                set "COLL=%%~C"
                setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            )
        )
        rem // Rename directory only when needed:
        if defined FLAG ren "!NAME!" "!COLL:~2!"
        endlocal
    )
    rem // Return from target directory:
    popd
)

endlocal
exit /B


:REPLACEMENT  var_return  var_string  var_replace  val_position
    setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
    set "#RTN=%~1" & rem // (return variable)
    set "#STR=%~2" & rem // (original string by reference)
    set "#RPL=%~3" & rem // (replacement string by reference)
    set "_POS=%~4" & rem // (start character position in original string by value)
    set /A "POS=_POS*!(_POS>>31)" & rem // (ensure position to be numeric and positive)
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion & set "RES=" & set "STR=!%#STR%!" & if defined STR (
        rem // Ensure position to not exceed length of original string:
        call :LENGTH NUM STR & set /A "POS-=((NUM-POS)>>31)*(NUM-POS)"
        rem // Determine end position of replacement:
        set "RPL=!%#RPL%!" & call :LENGTH NUM RPL !POS!
        rem // Do replacement with case of replacement string as given:
        for %%I in (!POS!) do for %%J in (!NUM!) do set "RES=!STR:~,%%I!!RPL!!STR:~%%J!"
        rem // Loop through replaced character positions and adapt cases there:
        set /A "NUM-=1" & set "UPC=" & for /L %%I in (!POS!,1,!NUM!) do (
            set "CHR=!STR:~%%I,1!" & if defined CHR call :GETCASE UPC CHR
            set "CNV=!RES:~%%I,1!" & call :SETCASE CNV CNV !UPC!
            set /A "NXT=%%I+1" & for %%J in (!NXT!) do (
                set "RES=!RES:~,%%I!!CNV!!RES:~%%J!"
            )
        )
    )
    rem // Assign resulting string to return variable:
    for /F delims^=^ eol^= %%E in ("%#RTN%=!RES!") do (
        endlocal & endlocal & set "%%E"
    )
    exit /B
    
    
:GETCASE  var_return  var_string  val_position
    setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
    set "#RTN=%~1" & rem // (return variable)
    set "#STR=%~2" & rem // (string by reference)
    set "_POS=%~3" & rem // (character position in string by value)
    set /A "_POS+=0" & rem // (ensure position to be numeric)
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion & set "RES=" & set "STR=!%#STR%!"
    rem // Change character at position to upper-case and compare with original:
    if defined STR if _POS geq 0 (set "STR=!STR:~%_POS%,1!") else set "STR="
    if defined STR call :SETCASE CHR STR # & if "!CHR!"=="!STR!" set "RES=#"
    rem // Assign resulting upper-case flag to return variable:
    endlocal & endlocal & set "%#RTN%=%RES%"
    exit /B
    
    
:SETCASE  var_return  var_string  val_upper
    setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
    set "#RTN=%~1" & rem // (return variable)
    set "#STR=%~2" & rem // (string by reference)
    set "_FLG=%~3" & rem // (upper-case flag by value)
    rem // Define letters depending on whether upper-case flag is set (defined):
    if defined _FLG (
        set "_CHR=A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z"
    ) else (
        set "_CHR=a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z"
    )
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion & set "STR=!%#STR%!"
    rem // Do replacement of all (ASCII) letters by upper-case or lower-case ones:
    if defined STR for %%C in (%_CHR%) do set "STR=!STR:%%C=%%C!"
    rem // Assign resulting string to return variable:
    for /F delims^=^ eol^= %%E in ("%#RTN%=!STR!") do (
        endlocal & endlocal & set "%%E"
    )
    exit /B
    
    
:LENGTH  var_return  var_string  val_offset
    setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
    set "#RTN=%~1" & rem // (return variable)
    set "#STR=%~2" & rem // (string by reference)
    set "_OFF=%~3" & rem // (offset by value)
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion & set "STR=!%#STR%!"
    rem // Determine character length of string and add offset:
    if not defined STR (set /A "LEN=_OFF") else set /A "LEN=_OFF+1" & (
        for %%I in (4096 2048 1024 512 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1) do (
            if not "!STR:~%%I!"=="" set /A "LEN+=%%I" & set "STR=!STR:~%%I!"
        )
    )
    rem // Assign resulting number to return variable:
    endlocal & endlocal & set "%#RTN%=%LEN%"
    exit /B
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in `cmd` function to do this. You can use `if` statements or like I do here using `findstr` and `errorlevel` and then `set` what the outcome will be.

```
@echo off
chcp 1252 > Nul
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:: Folder structure to be renamed:
set "Folder=C:\Users\Ricardo\Desktop\Clientes"

:: Phrase to be renamed:
set "Ori1=RESCICAO"

For /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /ad "%Folder%" ^& echo %Folder% ^|sort /r ^|find /i "%Ori1%"') do call :Rename1 "%%a"
goto :eof
:Rename1
echo "%~1"|findstr "RESCICAO">nul && set "Sub1=RESCISAO"
echo "%~1"|findstr "ReScIcao">nul && set "Sub1=ReScIsao"
echo "%~1"|findstr "Rescicao">nul && set "Sub1=Rescisao"
set "NameP1=%~nx1"
if not "!NameP1:%Ori1%=%Sub1%!"=="%~nx1" ren "%~1" "!NameP1:%Ori1%=%Sub1%!"
```

Comment: So you have to create a IF for every possibility of cases? And why is the goto :eof after the for and not on the end of the rename function?

Comment: Pretty much yes. `goto :eof` is there to to goto the end of the file so your script does not fall through the `:Rename` label when the `for` loop is done.

Comment: I made it slightly less complicated by using `&&` conditional operator.

Comment: Ok thanks, there was an exit before the for to prevent the rename to run again...

Comment: `goto :eof` is a better option.. if you run this from cmd to test, it will not `exit` the console window.

Answer (score 0):

Windows command processor `cmd.exe` is designed for running commands and executables. It has only a very limited support for string manipulations. For that reason the task is very hard to do using only [Windows Commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands). Other scripting languages like Visual Basic and JScript both interpreted by Windows Script Host (`cscript.exe` or `wscript.exe`) or PowerShell are much more suitable for such a folder renaming task, especially if find and replace string are of different length.

However, I suggest following batch file with some comments (remarks):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "NoPrompt="
if /I "%~1" == "/Q" set "NoPrompt=Yes"
%SystemRoot%\System32\chcp.com 1252 >nul

rem Folder structure to be renamed:
set "Folder=%UserProfile%\Desktop\Clientes"

rem Phrase to be renamed in most common variants:
set "FindCap=Rescicao"
set "FindLower=rescicao"
set "FindUpper=RESCICAO"

rem To be substituted by these most common variants:
set "ReplaceCap=Rescisao"
set "ReplaceLower=rescisao"
set "ReplaceUpper=RESCISAO"

for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir "%Folder%" /AD /B /S 2^>nul ^& echo %Folder%^| %SystemRoot%\System32\sort.exe /R ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /I "%Ori1%"') do call :RenameFolder "%%I"
rem endlocal is done here implicit by cmd.
goto :EOF

:RenameFolder
set "FolderNameNow=%~nx1"
set "FolderPath=%~dp1"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem Ignore subfolders not containing the string to find
rem and replace in folder name itself, just in their paths.
if /I "!FolderNameNow!" == "!FolderNameNow:%FindCap%=%ReplaceCap%!" endlocal & goto :EOF
rem Has the folder name the string to find with just first character
rem in uppercase and all other characters in lowercase (capitalized)?
if "!FolderNameNow!" == "!FolderNameNow:%FindCap%=%FindCap%!" (
    ren "!FolderPath!!FolderNameNow!" "!FolderNameNow:%FindCap%=%ReplaceCap%!"
    endlocal & goto :EOF
)
rem Has the folder name the string to find with all characters in uppercase?
if "!FolderNameNow!" == "!FolderNameNow:%FindUpper%=%FindUpper%!" (
    ren "!FolderPath!!FolderNameNow!" "!FolderNameNow:%FindUpper%=%ReplaceUpper%!"
    endlocal & goto :EOF
)
rem Has the folder name the string to find with all characters in lowercase?
if "!FolderNameNow!" == "!FolderNameNow:%FindLower%=%FindLower%!" (
    ren "!FolderPath!!FolderNameNow!" "!FolderNameNow:%FindLower%=%ReplaceLower%!"
    endlocal & goto :EOF
)
rem This is the worst case scenario with find string in uncommon mixed case.
rem The user of the batch file should enter the new folder name. There
rem is suggested the new folder name with capitalized replace applied.
set "FolderNameNew=!FolderNameNow:%FindCap%=%ReplaceCap%!"
if not defined NoPrompt (
    echo/
    echo Folder name is: !FolderNameNow!
    echo Preferred name: !FolderNameNew!
    echo/
    echo Enter new folder name or press ENTER to use preferred name.
    echo/
    set /P "FolderNameNew=New folder name: "
    set "FolderNameNew=!FolderNameNew:"=!"
    if not defined FolderNameNew set "FolderNameNew=!FolderNameNow:%FindCap%=%ReplaceCap%!"
)
ren "!FolderPath!!FolderNameNow!" "!FolderNameNew!"
endlocal
goto :EOF
```

It can be seen at bottom that the task to replace something like `ReScIcAo` in folder name is hand over to the user of the batch file with suggesting to use the folder name with find string replaced by capitalized replace string. The batch file can be started with optional parameter `/Q` (case-insensitive) to avoid the prompt and do the folder rename with find string replaced by capitalized variant in worst case scenario.

This batch file works also for folders with one or more exclamation marks in name or path.

`echo %Folder%` in `for` command line could be a problem on folder name containing `&` or `)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "targetdir=U:\sourcedir\t w o"

set "alphabet=A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z"

:: From and to strings in lower-case

set "fromstring=rescicao"
set "tostring=rescisao"

:: Step 1 - Create from/to.1 as lower-case; from/to.2 as UPPER-CASE; from/to.3 as Proper-case
set "from.1=%fromstring%"
set "to.1=%tostring%"
call :changecase from.2 from.1 %alphabet%
call :changecase to.2 to.1 %alphabet%
set "from.3=%from.2:~0,1%%from.1:~1%"
set "to.3=%to.2:~0,1%%to.1:~1%"

FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /ad "%targetdir%\*%fromstring%*" '
 ) DO (
 set "oname=%%a"
 for /L %%v in (1,1,3) do (
  for /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%L in ('set from.%%v') do ( 
   echo %%a|find "%%M" >nul
   if not errorlevel 1 call :chgname %%v 
  )
 )
 if defined oname call echo "%%oname%%" not changed
)

GOTO :EOF

:: Make change
:chgname
for /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%r in ('set to.%1') do call set "nname=%%oname:%fromstring%=%%s%%"
echo ren "%targetdir%\%oname%" "%nname%"
set "oname="
goto :eof

:: Change case of value %2 to variable %1

:changecase
set "_dest=%1"
shift
call set "%_dest%=%%%1%%"
:loop
shift
if "%1"=="" goto :eof
call set "%_dest%=%%%_dest%:%1=%1%%"
goto loop
```

Not really enough data to go on. There appear to be three case of interest - lower-case names, upper-case names an Proper-case names.

This approach establishes `from.1`..`from.3` as the three strings of interest and `to.1`..`to.3` as the replacement strings.No doubt if such patterns as `RESCICaO 2` are to be processed, then - well, follow the bouncing ball - create `from.4` etc.

Next step is the familiar `for` for directory-names delivering `%%a` as the name within the target directory. Each name found is assigned to `oname` (original name) and a loop using `%%v` to cycle through each of the `from/to.%%v` variables (hence I used numeric designations).

We then examine the name found for the `from.%%v` string - using `find` and a case-sensitive search. If a match is found, the `:chgname` subroutine is executed and the `%%v` value supplied to that routine as `%1`.

The `:chgname` routine constructs the new name in `nname` by substituting into `oname`.

Note that if a name such as `RESCICaO 2` appears then it will not match any of `from.1`..`from.3` and the `:chgname` routine will not be executed. Hence, by clearing the value of `oname` if the routine *IS* executed then if `oname` survives, it has not been renamed and thus is reported.

Comment: Thanks for your time, really appreciate it.